# Else Statement which shouldn't be reached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, enums

I stumbled on this issue while coding a new Unity Project. I'm still learning certain things about C# but to my understanding the following error shouldn't be possible. If in fact I'm wrong and there is an obvious explanation for this I would be glad to learn it.

The important code bits are as follows:

The declaration of the public `enum`:

```cs
public enum RoadDirection
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

The function which gets called to select a random value from the `enum`:

```cs
RoadDirection GetRoadDirection()
{
    int randomDir = Random.Range(0, 4);
    switch (randomDir)
    {
        case 0:
            return RoadDirection.Up;
        case 1:
            return RoadDirection.Down;
        case 2:
            return RoadDirection.Right;
        case 3:
            return RoadDirection.Left;
        default:
            return RoadDirection.Up;
    }
}
```

The `if`-statement which uses the function:

```cs
if (GetRoadDirection() == RoadDirection.Up)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (GetRoadDirection() == RoadDirection.Down)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (GetRoadDirection() == RoadDirection.Left)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (GetRoadDirection() == RoadDirection.Right)
{
    // does stuff
}
else
{
    // shouldn't even happen but does stuff
}
```

Those are the only parts in my script which are relevant/using the function.
Is there a reason why the `else` gets triggered even if all possibilities are already covered?

I added the `else`-statement to debug if this was where the error was occurring,
with the `else` it's already fixed but still the reason behind it would be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you call the `GetRoadDirection` method in every `if` condition. Since the method returns a random value each time, there's only a 25% chance that any condition will ever be true. Instead, you should capture the value once and store it, and then do your evaluation:

```cs
var direction = GetRoadDirection();

if (direction == RoadDirection.Up)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (direction == RoadDirection.Down)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (direction == RoadDirection.Right)
{
    // does stuff
}
else if (direction == RoadDirection.Left)
{
    // does stuff
}
else
{
    // shouldn't ever happen
}
```

One way to do this without explicitly capturing the value would be to use a `switch` statement (and `switch` will capture the value internally):

```cs
switch (GetRoadDirection())
{
    case RoadDirection.Up:
        // does stuff
        break;
    case RoadDirection.Down:
        // does stuff
        break;
    case RoadDirection.Right:
        // does stuff
        break;
    case RoadDirection.Left:
        // does stuff
        break;
    default:
        // shouldn't ever happen
        break;
}
```

As a side note, you can cast an `int` to an `enum`, so your `GetRoadDirection` method could be simplified to:

```cs
RoadDirection GetRoadDirection()
{
    return (RoadDirection) Random.Range(0, 4);
}
```

Comment: This could also be done using a `switch`.

Comment: That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Ah true, I wasnt even thinking about that. Thanks